# MediaElement takes too much time during loading

Tags: wpf, time, load, mediaelement

i am new to wpf. i am using MediaElement for display video from web. Everything is works well Except it takes too much time before loading. i use following code for set source and play the video

```
 Path_MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(_videoPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            if (!IsVideoStart)
            {
                progressImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                this.UpdateLayout();
            }
            Path_MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Original file size is around 85 MB. It takes around 7-10 minute to load data in buffer and after that it start. However once it play the video, then it takes less time to buffering data(around 30 sec.). So i want to ask that how can i minimize the first load time.

Comment: provide feedback on previous questions you've asked (mark answers OR comment on why they're invalid)